# firebase.auth.currentUser phoneNumber returning null

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve the phone number for a user from firebase. However, it is the only data field that returns null. I have been testing it from my own google account and I know that my phone number is registered. I don't understand why it returns null.

Comment: Are you going through the Firebase phone verification flow or are you using phone number sign in via Google OAuth flow? If so, Firebase only supports the former. If you have a phone number via Google sign-in, it will not be set on currentUser.phoneNumber.

Comment: I am using firebase google sign in flow. How would I retrieve the phone number from firebase in that case?

Comment: Kindly requesting a folllowup @bojeil

Comment: Unfortunately, Google sign-in does not expose a user's phone number to begin with, making it not possible for Firebase Auth to get that. If you wish to get a user's phone number you would need to go through Firebase phone auth flow. If you are using Google sign in, you can link a phone number provider to an account. The same user would be able to sign in with a Google provider or the phone number associated with that account.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. So I should probably prompt the user to input their phone number when they first sign in?

Comment: Yeah, you can check if a phone number is available on the currentUser, if not, prompt the user to verify their phone number and then go through the phone number verification flow to set it on that user.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thank you again for your support

Comment: You're welcome, Nithin.